# JDK 8 is MIA on my Mac, how can I find and remove it?

Tags: java, macos, installation, uninstallation

So, long story short I installed jdk-8u74-macosx-x64.dmg to do some development work in intellij, installation and setup was fine and I was able to select in intellij no problem.

But I soon discovered that the version of grails I wanted to use is incompatible for various as yet unsolved reasons so I want to revert to 7.

I downloaded jdk-7u79-macosx-x64.dmg and run the install I but cannot find where it was installed, looking in the java system preferences stuff it doesnt look like its installed or selectable in there in the "View/manage Java runtime" section :/

For some information on what my machine seems to have on it my current `java -version` returns `java version "1.8.0_74"`.

Finding it to set up my JAVA_HOME etc originally was a PITA but I ended up finding it in the Java system preferences path which pointed to the following path: -

```
/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home
```

I don't seem to have a Library/Java folder if I try to go to the path above there is nothing inside my Internet Plug-Ins folder at all (I've unhidden hidden files and there is still nothing there in finder, if I navigate to this folder in a terminal window and type `ls -lah` I get this: -

```
total 0
drwx------+  2 petercopper  staff    68B  1 Mar 20:33 .
drwx------@ 54 petercopper  staff   1.8K 20 Apr 07:34 ..
```

How can I delete java 8?

The oracle websites instructions tell you to go to the Java folder in Library, which I dont have.  And running the JDK 7 install doesn't seem to work when 8 is present...

Any ideas on how to remove 8 or install and select 7 would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you use an IDE then just tell the IDE to use the old Java 7 JDK for your programs.

Comment: I can't, I tried to install JAVA 7 but as JAVA 8 is already present this appears to cause problems, hence hwy I want to remove 8, its not showing up in the IDE at all after install because I dont think the JAVA_HOME is set properly, but again as stated above I cant find where its installed...

Comment: What does `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` say?

Comment: Apologie for the delay in response, when I enter this command I get the following output: - 

`Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    1.8.0_74, x86_64: "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.7.0_79, x86_64: "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_74.jdk/Contents/Home`

So it looks like I have something installed but I cannot see those folders :(

Comment: Ive set my JAVA_HOME to the 1.7 path given above and this seems to have done the trick, although Im still unsure how to make the Library/Java path available to me... :(

Comment: "Cannot see those folders"?  That means?  You should be able to use cd in a terminal.

Comment: I cant get to them if I go to the Library folder and type `cd Java` I get back `-bash: cd: Java: No such file or directory`